Dice game with token system
The following question is from an online assessment:

You have a selection of three dice, and 10 tokens with which you will play a game. The dice are a d3 which costs 1 token per roll, a d6 which costs 2 tokens, and a d12 which costs 3 tokens. You can roll as many times as you want until you run out of tokens (you may not go below 0 tokens), and if you want, you can stop playing without using all of your tokens. If your final score (sum of all rolls) is a multiple of 10, then you get paid your score in \$. If your final score is not a multiple of 10, you get nothing.


A) Which die would you choose for your first roll, and why? You don’t need to provide a numeric answer to this, just a qualitative justification.


B) You have 3 tokens left, and a score so far of 18. Which die do you want to roll? What is the expected value of your winnings?


C) You have a choice to either play this exact game (with 10 tokens) twice, or play an 18-token version of this game once. Which do you choose, and why? Assume you are trying to maximise the expected value of the number of \$ you earn. Please explain any positives or negatives of choosing the 18-token game, and assert which choice you find more compelling. You don’t need to provide an expected value for either game, just a qualitative justification.

My answers are as follows. Please let me know if they're rationale and your suggested answers:
A) Since we want to maximize our profits and we aren't concerned about hitting a multiple of 10 just yet, I would choose a d12.
B) In this case, the best and safest die to choose would be the d3, since the expected value of d3 is 2. In the best case, we can either roll a 2 or two 1s in a row and have 20 (a multiple of 10) and receive the payout. The expected value of my winnings would be 20*(1/3 + 1/9) = ~ \$8.89
C) Since we are trying to maximize our payout, I would choose the 18-token option. This is because, the most we can make from a single 10-token game is \$30, and the most we can make from the 18-token version is \$70. We don't have control over what the dice roll, so both versions are risky (although the 18-token might be slightly riskier). But in the end, out goal is to maximize profit, therefore, 18-token game is the best option for this.
Positive: Higher payout, Negative: constricted to only 1 chance.
What do you think?

What are you trying to optimise? Expected value of final score in all of A, B and C?

Yes, I believe.

70 is greater than 30, ok, but it is not the good reason to choose 18-token game. Imagine a game where you can win 70$ with a very low probability $p_0$, and another game where can win 30$ with a high probability $p_1$ ; the expected value is $70 p_0$ in one case , and $30 p_1$in the other case. What you want to maximize is this expected value. So you play the 2nd game.

2nd as in the 10-token game?
Let's say with the 10-token game, in the best scenario, we roll 12 thrice, and the fourth roll is a 4, this happens with a probability 0.0096%, with the 18-token game, we can not only, have this sequence, but also have 8 tokens left, which can maximize our profit. My point is we can make any sequence the 10-token game has with the 18-token game and still make more from it. Although, I am not sure about how to account for the 18-token having one chance and the 10-token having 2 chances.
Am I missing something?

You cannot cash in unused tokens.

Personally, I also favor the 18-token game.  Intuitively, the difficulty with the 2 x 10-token game is that you only get 10 tokens per game, so it is perhaps not the right play to use 2 of the D12's, since that leaves you with only 4 tokens left.  In the 18-token game, you have the option of using 3 D12's, which might immediately takes you into the big money, but still leaves you with 9 tokens, which seems like reasonable flexibility.  Naturally, if the first D12 is 7-9, you have to reconsider.

The question says "maximize our payout", so I too believe the safe and best option is 18-token. Any math behind it to prove me wrong?

I suspect that "Beat the Dealer" by Thorpe (in the 1960's), which discussed beating the 1960's version of blackjack, was based on computer simulations.  I would use computer simulations on this problem to get a conclusive answer.  The difficulty is that you have to derive an optimal strategy, so you have to consider/discard many strategies until you find the optimal 10-token and 18-token strategies.  This could take months.

The exercise says : Assume you are trying to maximise the expected value of the number of $ you earn. I think that you did not correctly catch the meaning of 'expected value'. And when you say 'maximize our payout' instead of 'maximize the expected value of our payout', it confirms that you don't correctly treat this problem.

Imagine same game, with very small changes. You can play with 11 tokens twice (11 instead of 10), and 2nd option is now 19 tokens instead of 18. Maximum payout if I am very lucky is $40 \times 2=80$ if I choose 11 tokens twice and maximum is $70$ if I choose 19 tokens ; Is it enough to conclude that 11 tokens twice is better than 19 tokens once ?

The maths to say which strategy is the best are not complex, but they need long time to try all scenarios. I think that the best strategy is 18 tokens once, but not sure at all.

@Lourrran I consider this posted question much more difficult to analyze than blackjack.

You don't need to consider every possible complete strategy individually, you just need to compute the optimal move and its mean value from every possible state (current score, tokens left), where the values of all states (s, 0) are already known. Since the number of tokens always decreases, there are no cycles in the transition graph, so this only takes a single pass ("backward induction"). This should take a computer less than a second.

@HighDiceRoller Less than a millisecond.

I am not expert with Python, but I was finally able to do this :
import numpy as np 
ttt1 = np.zeros(2200) 
def expect  ( startingscore, nbtokens ):
    nb1=0.0
    nb2=0.0
    nb3=0.0
    nb0=0.0
    if nbtokens > 2 :
        for i in range(12):
            nb3 = nb3 + ttt1 [ ( startingscore+i+1 ) * 20 +  nbtokens-3] 
        nb3 = nb3 / 12
    if nbtokens > 1 :
        for i in range(6):
            nb2 = nb2 + ttt1 [ ( startingscore+i+1 ) * 20 +  nbtokens-2] 
        nb2 = nb2 / 6
    if nbtokens > 0 :
        for i in range(3):
            nb1 = nb1 + ttt1 [( startingscore+i+1 ) * 20 + nbtokens-1] 
        nb1 = nb1 / 3
    if startingscore%10==0 :
        nb0 = startingscore
    return max(nb0, nb1,nb2, nb3)

for nbt in range ( 20):
    for sc in range(90):
        ttt1[ sc * 20 + nbt] = expect( sc, nbt  )
print ( ttt1 [18] )
print ( ttt1 [10]*2 )

Result is 20.391 for option 18 tokens and 17.213 for option 10 tokens twice.

My own programmed evaluation gives the same results.
